# How to copy a database from server to localhost

Tags: database, mongodb, ssh, server

I'm trying to copy a database from a server (to which I'm connected through ssh) to my localhost. But all that I find is using the `copyDatabase()` method which is now deprecated, and the documentation doesn't explain how to do something similar (Or I didn't understand how to)
Also, I'd like to know how can I generalize that to also copy a DB from atlas if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using mongodb then its like

step 1: create a tunnel

```
ssh username@yourdomainOrIP -L 27017:localhost:27017
```

step 2 :

```
mongo
use admin
db.copyDatabase(<fromdb>,<todb>,"localhost:27017",<username>,<password>)
```

Comment: As I said, copyDatabase is [deprecated since version 4.0](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/#mongodb-method-db.copyDatabase)

Comment: You can use mongodump for exporting whole database and use mongorestore to getting it on new host machine or you can use mongoexport for exporting a collection as json or csv and use mongoimport for using it.

Answer (score 0):

1. [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/) dump either whole database or a specific collection
2. [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/) restore to your local database

Comment: Yeah, I read that from documentation, but I don't understand how to achieve properly the process trough an ssh connection.